# RuntimeError while executing python

Tags: error, matplotlib

After downloading Matplotlib to use the Statist Pugin An error has occured while executing Python code:

RuntimeError: module compiled against API version 9 but this version of numpy is 6

Python version:
2.7.5 (default, Mar  9 2014, 22:15:05) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 5.0 (clang-500.0.68)]

QGIS version:
2.2.0-Valmiera Valmiera,

Later on the message is that statist is also not able to run. 
How to solve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20999939/opencv-2-4-8-module-compiled-against-api-version-9

Answer (score 2):

It simply means that you do not have the correct numpy version for matplotlib

From your Python shell, you are on Mac OS X (Apple)

1) how did you install matplotlib ?
2) which is your version of QGIS: from [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis), Homebrew, other ?
3) which version of Python do you use: Apple Python, Homebrew Python, ?

If you use the [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis) distribution, it use the Apple Python and his matplotlib module use his numpy  module (version 1.8.0) ([KyngChaos: Python modules](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python))

Try in the shell (Terminal.app)

```
python
....
import numpy
print numpy.__version__
??? # -> 1.8.0
```

If not, download/install the correct numpy version or use your installed version of numpy to install/compile matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

if you're using Mac OS X do this:

1. http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/python
2. download bumpy file
3. install
4. open QGIS
5. TCHARAN!

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange :)  Use the [edited x time ago] link above to see how I reformatted your answer so the list displays properly.  Another improvement is to go beyond bare recipe, try and educate. Something more along the lines of _"The error message indicates the wrong version of `___` is installed or can't be located. Try installing the latest from  `___` from `www.___`. For example:...."_